# Scikit-learn data indexing and referencing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used GridsearchCV to train multiple different models. During training, the data was ordered as follows:

```
[feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, feature 4]
```

I want to use the saved (saved with joblib) models to predict on new data. The new/unseen data is ordered as follows:

```
[feature 1, feature 2, feature 4, feature 3]
```

The features are the same between the training data and the new data (i.e. feature 1 represents the same thing between the two datasets).

Does the ordering of the input data matter to scikit learn? Does it reference by index similar to pandas iloc or does it reference by name similar to pandas loc?

Answer (score 0):

It should reference by index, so you need to reindex the features.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn models return arrays. So order, and keeping a copy of ordered feature list is important if you will train a model, save it and use it later for predictions with different data following the same preprocessing steps.